# Question on Time Speed and Distance .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Two friends started from A to B in the same direction along a straight line simultaneously.
>   The faster friend john was on bike , while ron was on bicycle.
>   The ratio of their speeds was $1:5$.
>   Two hours later john parked his bike and started running back towards ron's bicycle.
>   He's speed dropped by $80\%$ as a result of this.
>   They meet at point which is $15$ km from B.
>   what was the speed of bicycle?

**Options**
$a.)\quad 2\quad  km/hr \\
\color{green}{b.)\quad 2.5\quad  km/hr} \\
c.)\quad 3\quad  km/hr \\
d.)\quad \text{none} $

[image]

Let the speed of cycle be $x.$
So the speed of bike is $5x$.

Upto $2$ hrs john covered a distance of $10x.$

and ron covered upto $2$ hrs ron covered $2x$.

so they meet at point D.

after john left the bike he's speed was reduced $80\%$ and his  running speed was equal to ron's bicycle.

So they covered equal distance of $4x$ from C and E.

and according to information given 
$m+4x=15$. now i am stucked.

Comment: Do you mean (b) is the answer? It makes some sense if the correct answer is (d), since maybe the problem implies that John returned when he arrived at B.

Comment: I am not sure , answer in book is (b.) that's why marked it green.

Comment: I think the answer could only be (b) if the point they meet is 15km from A instead of B.

Comment: i checked  it, it is B .

Comment: Another possibility for the answer to be (b) :) : did they start from B to A? I just cannot see how you can calculate the speed without anyone touching the point B.